# I am trying to use PIVOT to convert rows to columns. I only have numeric examples, but I need to PIVOT with varchar

Tags: sql

Need to convert the following

```
Country , code , result
('IND','AC1','Completed'),
    ('IND','AC2','Completed'),
    ('IND','AC3','Completed'),
    ('SL','AC1','Status'),
    ('SL','AC2','ERROR'),
    ('AUS','AC3','Completed')
```

into

```
Country , ac1 , ac2 , ac3
------------------------
ind , Completed , Completed , Completed
sl, Status ,Error
AUS, , ,Completed
```

Comment: Reformat your question, it hurts me eye I can't read it

Comment: I removed the incompatible SQL tags.  But the basic idea is that you would use `MAX()` instead of `SUM()` in whatever code you have that works for numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    Country
  , max(case when code = 'AC1' then result else '' end) as AC1
  , max(case when code = 'AC2' then result else '' end) as AC2
  , max(case when code = 'AC3' then result else '' end) as AC3
from countries
group by Country
```

using `pivot()` in SQL Server:

```
select 
    Country
  , coalesce(AC1,'') as AC1
  , coalesce(AC2,'') as AC2
  , coalesce(AC3,'') as AC3
from countries
pivot (max(result) for code in (AC1,AC2,AC3)) p
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZTLYWY22412

returns (for both):

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Country |    AC1    |    AC2    |    AC3    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| AUS     |           |           | Completed |
| IND     | Completed | Completed | Completed |
| SL      | Status    | ERROR     |           |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Sorry for the unformatted question. I'll take care of it next time